# Google Maps: Show results with multiple statuses

Tags: forms, google-maps, status

In [Google Maps](https://objectivehtml.com/google-maps), I'm using `{exp:gmap:search}` and `{exp:gmap:results}` to create a search form and results listing.

How can I show entries with multiple statuses?

I know I can put a hidden field in the search form to specify a single status: `<input type="hidden" name="status" value="pending" />`, but I'm not sure how to search multiple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the current version doesn't allow OR modifiers to the search. I think this would be a good feature request, and I can definitely work into the release after next. (v3.2)

In theory, the markup would be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="status[]" value="pending" />
<input type="hidden" name="status[]" value="open" />
```

But currently (as of 3.0.17), this would search `status = 'pending' AND status = 'open'`.